# React Native UI Kittens: Multiple lines in Input Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

How can the [`Input`](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/input/overview#input) component in [`react-native-ui-kitten`](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten) be styled such that it will show multiple lines (when there is no input value)?

**Problem:** Tried passing the `multiline` and `numberOfLines` props to `<Input />`. Doing so only allows the number of lines to increase. It still shows one single line when there is no user input.

```
import { Input, withStyles } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

<Input 
    label='Message' 
    placeholder='Enter your long message..' 
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={5}
    style={[themedStyle.input, {}]}
    textStyle={themedStyle.inputText}
    labelStyle={themedStyle.inputLabel}
/>
```

**Current Behavior**

[image]

[image]

**Expected Behavior:** `Input` component should show 5 lines without any input value.

*Running on React Native v0.57.1, expo v2.21.2 and a physical iPhone on iOS 12.2*

Comment: add `minHeight` to your style, like `style={{ minHeight: 50 }}`